# Inno Setup: deltree function

Tags: inno-setup

We are using deltree function to delete the directories,but in some cases it is unable to delete the directory and it is returning boolean values. But, we need to capture the reason for the error in the log, is there any way to get exact reason why deltree is unable to delete the directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for Inno Setup 5 (available from the web site) shows that `DelTree` (in `InstFunc.pas`) has five places where it sets `Result := False;`, all of which are as the result of other function calls. It doesn't use `SetLastError` anywhere, so you'd have to check the documentation or source (in Inno Setup) for those other function calls to see if any of them do so.

(One of the five places is the user callback you can set yourself, so you'd know if that uses `SetLastError` if you were providing one, so that reduces it to four places. Another is a recursive call to `DelTree` itself, so that would eliminate it as well.)